# Ajax search in modal

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I try to implement a search from a Bootstrap theme inside a modal.

You can test the search and the modal here:

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=components/base/modal&demo=default

I implement the search on a simple html.erb page and works perfectly well. Here is the code:

```html
<div class="m-dropdown m-dropdown--large m-dropdown--align-center m-dropdown--mobile-full-width m-dropdown--skin-light m-dropdown--open m-list-search m-list-search--skin-light" id="m_quicksearch" m-dropdown-persistent="1" m-quicksearch-mode="dropdown">
  <div class="m-dropdown__wrapper">
    <div class="m-dropdown__inner">
      <div class="m-dropdown__header">
      <%= form_with url: search_path, local: true, method: :get, html: {class: "m-list-search__form"} do |form| %>
        <div class="m-list-search__form-wrapper">
          <span class="m-list-search__form-input-wrapper">
            <%= form.search_field :query, placeholder: "Search...", autocomplete: "off", class: "m-list-search__form-input", id: 'm_quicksearch_input' %>
          </span>
          <span class="m-list-search__form-icon-close" id="m_quicksearch_close">
            <i class="la la-remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="m-dropdown__body">
        <div class="m-dropdown__scrollable m-scrollable" data-height="300" data-mobile-height="200" data-scrollable="true">
          <div class="m-dropdown__content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I try to copy/past this theme inside my modal. When I start to write in the search field no queries are send.

Is it a CSS issue (z-index) or JS? How can I debug it?

Comment: there's no submit button, Is it typeahead search?if it is then yes, it's likely a js issue.

Comment: No, there is no submit, its autofill search. I don't think it's a typehead, it's custom js from the theme